# Trouble matching \u0002 using C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex, ascii

I am having trouble matching: `SD:             \u0002` using:
`Regex.Match(@"SD:             \u0002US^NE^STATE^12345^SOME NAME^\u0002\u0002STREETNAME\u0002ST\u0002\u0002\u00022115\u0004^NAME OF SOME ORG^^^ ", @"SD:\s\u0002")`

According to MS documentation, `\u nnnn` should be used to match `\u0002`.
Note: Source of the string is ASCII file, that was read with `Encoding.ASCII`, but VS Studio is showing Unicode `\u0002` character.

Comment: The first string is prefixed with @, so it will be interpreted literally.  The pattern however will be interpreted as escape sequences.  Remove @ from the first string.

Comment: Why do you have the space between the 'u' and the n's?  What MS documentation are you look at?  Normally in most application there is no space.

Comment: After you remove the @ you also need to match on more than one whitespace by putting `\s+`, with escaping the slash because you no longer have @: `"SD:\\s+\u0002"`.

Comment: @Quantic, ye you right ! I missing `+`

Comment: @CPerkins, could you write an answer, I could accept.

Comment: Apparently OmegaMan really wants the points, so be my guest and accept his plagiarized answer if you want, assuming Quantic doesn't mind since he also helped answer. I didn't post a formal answer, because I felt like this was a simple debugging exercise--the real problem wasn't about matching \u0002 as the question implies. It was about being careful of understanding every symbol and re-reading code. This type of problem could have been solved by paring down the test text and printing out the escaped strings to see what they actually return. Next time also be careful of what data you post.

Comment: "VS Studio is showing Unicode \u0002 character" that's right; A .NET string is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units. UTF-16 is one of several encodings for the Unicode character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@` in front of the data string so the C# compiler properly escapes the Unicode character.

But that **does not** apply to the pattern because the C# compiler needs it to be literal, but the following processing of the *regex parser will not read it as literal*.

Also you need `\s+` in your pattern because there is more than one space. This works for me by removing the `@` C# literal in front of the string but not the pattern in an edited example:

```
Regex.Match("SD:  \u0002US", @"\s+\u0002")
```